# raise KeyError(key) with Pandas

Tags: python

DataFrame looks okay but I'm getting key error when I attempt sorting by the `TXBS` column in descending order:

[image]

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)

data = pd.read_csv('intC.txt')
print(data)

mysort = data.sort_values(by=['TXBS'], ascending=False)
```

This is what the `intC.txt` file looks like:

[image]

Comment: can you post the output of data.columns

Comment: can you check any space in the column name?

Comment: Index(['  Interface                   IHQ       IQD       OHQ       OQD      RXBS      RXPS      TXBS      TXPS      TRTL'], dtype='object')

This is what data.columns returns

Comment: It looks like that your whole index is treated as a single key or single column and when you converting your  intC.txt to pandas dataframe, I think it would be inserted into a single pandas cell rather than in different cell that's why it is giving KeyError.

Comment: Can you share your intC.txt file? Let me try on my system, so that I can give you proper solution.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue - I'm looking for a way to "split" each of those elements in the header; no dice. File can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/intc Thanks

Comment: Try this  data = pd.DataFrame([i.split(';') for i in (intC.text).split('\n')])

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your script look like? I replaced my 'data' variable with what you just suggested; no dice. Did you try the file I shared with you? Also, your 'data' variable returns a list for each line - not sure how that will work out in the grand scheme since I'm trying to sort by a specific column.

Comment: Sir, I am using my company's laptop and link given by you is not opening my company's laptop due to company IT policy. Instead of semicolon try blank-space:  data = pd.DataFrame([i.split(' ') for i in (intC.text).split('\n')]). Hope it'll solve your issue.

Comment: the file has to be opened first and the contents assigned to a variable before applying DataFrame to a list comprehension of the variable. However, the result is the same as before: the column index appears to be a single key of the entire column.

Comment: Don't use anything inside first split function, try this-> `data = pd.DataFrame([i[0].split() for i in (intC.text).split('\n')])`. split() takes whitespace as the delimiter, it will automatically split your single key to different key. If this will not work send me your file on my mail ashu2717123@gmail.com.

Comment: you can't pass in a file into list comprehension.

Comment: I have passed my text file into list comprehension it worked for me, can you send your text file to me?

Comment: I just emailed you the file. My earlier point, is i don't see how you can leverage list comprehension on a text file without calling open on the file.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, use this `data = pd.DataFrame([i.split() for i in open("intC.txt", "r").readlines()])` I have posted full code and it's output in Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also to avoid `KeyError`, hope the below code will solve your issue:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([i.split() for i in open("intC.txt", "r").readlines()])
data.columns = data.iloc[0]
data = data.iloc[1: , :]
data['TXBS'] = pd.to_numeric(data['TXBS'], errors='coerce')
mysort = data.sort_values(by=['TXBS'], ascending=False)
```

[image]

Comment: TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None for no header or header=int or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making up the column names

Comment: Ashu007, not sure if you noticed, but looking at your output, 'TXBS' is not sorted.

Comment: Yes I have noticed that but previously your only problem was to eliminate key error, so I focused only on Key error, now further issues you should do it by yourself. First change the column into numeric type `data['TXBS'] = pd.to_numeric(data['TXBS'], errors = 'coerce'` and then apply `sort_values`, it'll definitely work. If you want change all the columns to numeric type use `for` loop to do that.